# How to check are there any OGRGeometry (polygons) within an OGRGeometry (polygon) ?

Tags: gdal, ogr

Please see my image:

[image: Multipolygon]

I used the below statements to get Geometry:

```
OGRGeometry *poGeometry;

poGeometry = poFeature->GetGeometryRef();
```

Do you know how to check whether the Polygon 1 (geometry) is empty (or include a small polygon) or not ?

If it is possible, how to get or identify the polygon 2 ?

Thanks and regards,

Tai

Comment: In somewhat theoretical terms---you'll want to consider the ring count for your polygons. A valid polygon has to have an outer ring (that's Polygon1 in your image), but inner rings, also called "holes" (Polygon2 in your image), are optional. So to answer your questions, first look for a ring count greater than 1, as this would indicate interior rings (holes), then you could parse the nodes of the inner ring(s) if you needed to derive the actual geometries of the holes for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @elrobis: But what is the function to check ring count ? I am finding out functions at the link: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometry.html      . Could you please give me some codes for example

Comment: It looks to me like maybe you're doing C++, which I don't know, but ultimately you'd want to cast from OGRGeometry to [OGRPolygon](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRPolygon.html), then consume the [getNumInteriorRings](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRPolygon.html#a3b996195adcf9fcd4f33570a37753dde), and possibly the [getInteriorRing](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRPolygon.html#af0bf0b1d1104e142b47637659518ad9c) methods. ..beware that to be bullet-proof, you need to evaluate whether you should be concerned about [MultiPolygons](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRMultiPolygon.html).

Comment: @elrobis : I tried to check NumInteriorRings but all return value: 0. I think it is a polygon and not a ring.